# SQL Sum() function with a condition

Tags: sql, function, join, sum, having

How does this work in SQL `sum(o.product_name='Bread') > 0`,
e.g if the orders table (o) has product_name column such that the entry is Bread then will the condition
`o.product_name='Bread'`  return 1 to the sum function and then the sum function will add all these ones ?

The Question is : There are 2 tables customers, orders. Find the customers who bought bread and milk but not eggs

```sql
Select  c.customer_id , c.customer_name
        FROM customers as c 
        left join
           orders as o
           on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
        group by c.customer_id , c.customer_name
        having 
        sum(o.product_name='Bread') > 0 
        and sum(o.product_name='Milk') > 0
        and sum(o.product_name='Eggs') = 0
        order by c.customer_name
```

```
Select  c.customer_id , c.customer_name
        FROM customers as c 
        left join
           orders as o
           on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
        group by c.customer_id , c.customer_name
        having 
        sum(o.product_name='Bread') > 0 
        and sum(o.product_name='Milk') > 0
        and sum(o.product_name='Eggs') = 0
        order by c.customer_name
```

Comment: You should include the DBMS that your are using (see details info under [tag:sql]).  To know why that is important see the the difference between these two DBFIDDLES: [mssql](https://dbfiddle.uk/XIfpS_0w) and [mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/uJTMuhn2)

Comment: Why did you post your SQL statement **two** times?  Please [edit] your question to make it (more) clear what your question is. (As I read it, it is just the "What does this do: `sum(o.product_name='Bread') > 0` ???)

Comment: (As you are a long-time-SO user) you should research/test/research more! (That's what most developers (should) do before asking a question) Just a simple way to start is in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/eAe6T1y6)

Answer (score -1):

As for your question, you need only those customers who bought both bread and milk but not eggs. I simply filters for the customers who bought both and then again do filtration to remove those who also bought eggs.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.product_name IN ('Eggs', 'Milk')
GROUP BY c.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.product_name) = 2
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN o.product_name = 'Bread' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```